# How did the aliens get to Earth in A Quiet Place?

Tags: a-quiet-place

In the film *A Quiet Place*, it seems that Earth has been overrun by blind extraterrestrials who only hunt what they can hear. However, it doesn't seem that the aliens are intelligent enough to have made it to the planet on their own. How did they get there in the first place? Was it completely unintentional? Did they hitch there way onto some kind of moving vessel (not technological, more natural)? Has this question been answered by a writer/producer/director?

Comment: Nice spoiler alert in your title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

John Krasinski, the director of *A Quiet Place*, discussed the aliens in an [April 11th Empire Film Podcast](https://soundcloud.com/empiremagazine/a-quiet-place-spoiler-special-ft-john-krasinski).  A [Collider article](http://collider.com/a-quiet-place-monsters-explained) transcribed several quotes from Krasinski from the podcast, in which he described how he formed his idea for the aliens and how they evolved:

> "They are absolutely aliens. They’re from another planet. Where I developed the idea of them and what I wanted them to look like was most alien movies are about takeovers, agendas, they’re a thinking alien creature, and for me this idea of a predator, this idea of a parasite, this idea of something that is introduced into an ecosystem [was interesting]. One of my favorite movies I love to watch is RocknRolla and they tell that whole story about the crawfish in the Thames and that’s what I mean, the introduction of something that can’t be held back."
>
> "I remember a terrible joke that I said was it would be—it’s disgusting and disturbing but it’s true—it would be like releasing wolves into a day care center. That’s how the world responds."
>
> "The idea behind all that is they’re definitely aliens and they’re an evolutionarily perfect machine. So the idea is if they grew up on a planet that had no humans and no light then they don’t need eyes, they can only hunt by sound. They also develop a way to protect themselves from everything else so that’s why they’re bulletproof and all these things."

He also said that something caused an explosion on the aliens' homeworld, resulting in meteoroids carrying the aliens to travel through space and crash on Earth:

> "And the other idea was [the armor is] also the reason why they were able to survive kind of the explosion of their planet and then survive on these meteorites, because they’ve evolved to be bulletproof. Until they open themselves up to be vulnerable, they’re completely invulnerable."

Comment: How this is relevant? This does not answer the OP's question about *how* they managed to travel to Earth with so primal instincts.

Comment: @Lefteris008 From the answer: "something caused an explosion on the aliens' homeworld, resulting in meteoroids carrying the aliens to travel through space and crash on Earth"

Answer (score 12):

There's a small scene with newspapers and it says, "Mexico struck by meteor!". I'm guessing that's how the aliens got there ?

Answer (score 4):

On one of the newspapers, it explains how there has been an alien invasion and there’s been over 1200 landing sights, and the picture is of a meteor or something coming through our atmosphere so it’s most likely the aliens reside on or within some form of celestial body or hoppped onto a passing asteroid that’s traveled through space and then reached earth naturally. However the aliens don’t seem intelligent or organised, they just attack whatever makes sound or  with sheer speed and force, suggesting the ‘invasion’ wasn’t a planned event and simply by chance and the only reason for the aliens success is there advanced evolved sound perception and hardened skin/exoskeleton.